# managing ManyToManyField to itself in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have the following model:

```
class MyUser(User):
    # some fields...
    contact = models.ManyToManyField("self", through='Contact', symmetrical=False, related_name="contact_set" )


class Contact(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey( MyUser, related_name="contact_set1")
    user2 = models.ForeignKey( MyUser, related_name="contact_set2")
    confirmed = models.BooleanField()
```

and this view to create a contact

```
def add_contact( request, username=None ):
    if username:
        try:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = None

    if user:
        contact = Contact( user1 = MyUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id), user2=user, confirmed=False )
        contact.save()
        return render_to_response( "accounts/add_contact.html", {'user': user,} )
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")

def list_contacts( request, username=None ):
    if username:
        try:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = None
    else:
        user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

    if user:
        contacts = user.contacts.all()
        return render_to_response("accounts/list_contacts.html", {'contacts': contacts,} )
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
```

Ok now... the code should be verbose enough, so I'll explain it briefly: Social networking, users add others to their contacts ("friends", "buddies", however you call it). If user A adds user B, B is also in contact with A...

The code works... but only one-way. If I'm logged in as user A and want to add user B to my contacts, B will show up on my contact list, but not the other way around. But I want also to show up on B's contact list - it should make no difference, who added whom. How may I manage that?

Comment: Ref: your comment. Sheesh, of course you are right. I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: having symmetrical=True in MyUser model, contact field definitions, should make it two way right ?. why is symmetrical set to False ?

Comment: Because it says in the docs: "When defining a many-to-many relationship from a model to itself, using an intermediary model, you must use symmetrical=False" -- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical). Docs says to pass "self"(as string).

Also, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721157/django-many-to-many-m2m-relation-to-same-model).

Good luck. I hope, you will succeed in development.