# Django Many-to-Many (m2m) Relation to same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I'd like to create a many-to-many relationship from and to a user class object.

I have something like this:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    ...
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
```

The question is if I can use the class reference inside itself. Or do I have to use `"self"` insead of `"MyUser"` in the `ManyToManyField`? Or is there another (and better) way to do it?

Comment: what is the use defining many to many on same model?? anyone please

Comment: @ParaM For example if you have a tree-like structure. Master product has subproduct etc etc.

Comment: *"what is the use defining many to many on same model??"* To allow each user to have their own list of other users they have blocked (or followed).

Comment: Best use-case is a tree-structure for the model.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Technically, I'm pretty sure "MyUser" or "self" will work, as long as it's a string in either case. You just can't pass `MyUser`, the actual class.

However, the docs always use "self". Using "self" is not only more explicit about what's actually happening, but it's impervious to class name changes. For example, if you later changed `MyUser` to `SomethingElse`, you would then need to update any reference to "MyUser" as well. The problem is that since it's a string, your IDE will not alert you to the error, so there's a greater chance of your missing it. Using "self" will work no matter what the class' name is now or in the future.

Comment: what is the use defining many to many on same model?? anyone please

Comment: @ParaM An example: an Article model where you wish to specify "related articles"

Comment: A personal example is an Agent with a field that specifies the agent that recruited them.

Answer (score 60):

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    ...
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

Comment: "self" doesn't work. Use blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField("MyUser", blank=True, null=True)

Comment: I didn't say "MyUser", I said "self": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Comment: `null=True` has no effect on ManyToManyFields

Answer (score 27):

Don't forget use symmetrical=False, if you use .clear() or .add() method for related objects and don't wanna object on other side of relation update own data in relation field.

```
some_field = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
```

ref: [Django Documentation: ManyToManyField.symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

Comment: This suggestion totally saved me! I was experiencing a cyclic dependency every time I would add a 'parent' relation to an entity and I was trying to debug it all day yesterday!

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be class name instead of self. because with using self like this

```
parent = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

when i add parent:

```
user1.parent.add(user2)
```

i have 2 record in database like this:
[image]

and with using class name liken this:

```
parent = models.ManyToManyField('User', null=True, blank=True)
```

i have one record in database like this:
[image]

note that i use uuid for pk and i use django 3.1

EDIT:
as @shinra-tensei explained as comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536346/6876911) we have to set `symmetrical` to False if we use self. documented in [Django Documents:  ManyToManyField.symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

Comment: What database adapter are you using? Might be a bug in there...

Comment: @Ron postgres and mysql both

Answer (score 3):

If you use **self** or **MyUser** you will get a NameError in both cases. You should write **"self"** as string. See the example below:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    ...
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)
```

And do not forget to set the **symmetrical** attribute to **False** if the relationship is not symmetrical.

For further details check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

Answer (score 0):

don't use 'self' in ManyToManyField, it will cause you object link each other, when use django form to submit it

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    ...
    subTag = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)

 ...
 aTagForm.save()
```

and result:

```
 a.subTag == b
 b.subTag == a
```

Comment: Any suggetions about it? I never had problems.

Comment: I was found it in my demo
and finally i use ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True) to fix it

Comment: If you don't want the objects to link each other, use the argument `symmetrical = False` when creating the field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical , it exists to allow you to use the `'self'` name instead of the name of the model