# Django foreign key to two different kind of objects

Tags: django, django-models, recursive-datastructures

I have two different models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # fields...

Class Child(models.Model):
    # if first child in the tree
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    # else
    # parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

I have only one Parent-node in my system and it can have multiple children and each of them can have multiple children etc. **What is the correct way to implement this kind of relationship?** I would like to see working example if someone knows how to handle this.

I red about django-mptt but it sounds overly complex for my needs. I'm actually modeling real human relationships in my system so usually parent node has only few children and some of them might have few children as well and there can be only four, maybe five generation alive at the same time. So usually tree contains something around ten nodes and even maximum is limited to some hundreds and that is extremely rare situation. In that perspective efficiency is not a big thing so I prefer the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ManyToMany relation with itself, as described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721157/django-many-to-many-m2m-relation-to-same-model).

Of course, your degsign needs to change, there's no Parent and Child, there's only Parent or Human or something, in the sense that everyone might be a parent someday :)

```
class Human(models.Model):
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
    other_info = ...
```

That [example page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and that [reference page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) will help you.

Be aware that this design doesn't protect you in any way from creating 'wrong' relation. A person could be his own father or grandfather or any kind of impossible situation. You need to check for this problem yourself before adding children in the database.

Comment: ManyToMany relation would not work because in my design each child can have only one parent. That's why I'm using ForeignKey. And that Parent class is completely different kind of class, it has only few same data fields than Child model has, it is the only model which can have two parents but those parents are different than those Child models etc. So I really need design where Child objects can have ForeignKey to two different kind of objects. Or then I have to make two different kind of Child models where only difference is the ForeignKey they are using.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear; maybe you should edit your question to add this information. "FK to two defferent kind of objects"? Read about [Generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). I never used them though, si I can't help you with that.