# Confusing field accessing on m2m field in a query set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, m2m

I have a django project with several models. Two of this models are:

```py
class Attack(models.Model):
    spell = models.ForeignKey("Spell", models.CASCADE, null=True)
    attacker = models.ForeignKey("Ent", models.CASCADE, related_name='attacker')
    defender = models.ForeignKey("Ent", models.CASCADE, related_name='defender')
    defender_pts_before = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    damage_caused = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
```

and

```py
class Ent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    raze = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    damage = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    weakness = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    health = models.FloatField(default=100, blank=False, null=False)
    attacks = models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Attack, symmetrical=False, related_name='attacked_from')
    battles = models.ManyToManyField(Battle, through=BattleParticipant, related_name='battles_part')
```

As you can see the `Ent` model has a m2m field to itself through the `Attack` model. This is for representing the attacks between ents. The attack model stores all the damage the attacker caused to the defender in the `damage_caused` field (which is calculated when the attack is saved).

I need to know for each ent the total damage it has caused in all the attacks, so I built the following query:

```py
Ent.objects.all().annotate(dmg=Sum('attacks__attacker__damage_caused'))
```

but this doesn't seems to work. It only seems to work the right way with this query:

```py
Ent.objects.all().annotate(dmg=Sum('attacks__defender__damage_caused'))
```

### Tests

I've created some entries to check the query (a single attack from one ent to another)

```py
In [106]: e1, e2  = Ent.objects.all().annotate(dmg=Sum('attacks__attacker__damage_caused'))[:2]

In [107]: e1, e2
Out[107]: (<Ent: Ent object (240)>, <Ent: Ent object (241)>)

In [108]: e1.attacks.all()
Out[108]: <QuerySet [<Ent: Ent object (241)>]>

In [109]: e2.attacks.all()
Out[109]: <QuerySet []>
```

As you can see `e1` only has one attack, and `e2` doesn't have any. Let's see this attack:

```py
In [110]: atk = Attack.objects.filter(attacker=e1).first()

In [111]: atk.attacker
Out[111]: <Ent: Ent object (240)>

In [112]: atk.defender
Out[112]: <Ent: Ent object (241)>

In [113]: atk.damage_caused
Out[113]: 20
```

All right, the attacker is `e1` and the defender is `e2`, but when I check the annotate values:

```py
In [114]: e1.dmg, e2.dmg
Out[114]: (None, None)
```

`e1` should had 20 in the total damage but both are None. The strange part comes when I do the following query:

```py
In [115]: e1, e2  = Ent.objects.all().annotate(dmg=Sum('attacks__defender__damage_caused'))[:2]

In [116]: e1, e2
Out[116]: (<Ent: Ent object (240)>, <Ent: Ent object (241)>)

In [117]: e1.dmg, e2.dmg
Out[117]: (20, None)
```

If I access to the attack by `defender` (instead of `attacker`) it gives me the right answer. So I'm a little confuse here. Why does this happen this way?

Comment: Hello @Jorge Morgado i think you have some logical error i will suggest to check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11723808/14457833

Comment: Hi, sorry but I can't see how this problem is related to that post. I have the m2m field already using `'self'` (as the post you cite). Am I missing something?